# Bootstrap text input wrong height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with bootstrap input text height size. I am using the standard bootstrap.css stylesheet and the searchform resides inside a navbar:

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-fixed-top m-header">
    <div class="navbar-inner m-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                ...

<!-- // START SEARCH BAR -->
<div class="span6 offset4">             
    <form>
      <div class="input-append" id="top-search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn" tabindex="-1">Search</button>
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
              <i class="icon-search"></i>aaa
            </label></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option2" checked>
              <i class="icon-th"></i>bbb
            </label></li>
            <li><label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option3" checked>
             <i class="icon-file"></i>ccc
            </label></li>
            <li><label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option4" checked>
              <i class="icon-inbox"></i>ddd
            </label></li>
            <li><label class="radio">
              <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option5" checked>
              <i class="icon-camera"></i>eee
            </label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- // END SEARCH BAR -->
...
```

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

I did some research and it could be that I was using the wrong doctype but I followed the bootstrap guide and had already set the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
```

I also checked if there was garbage characters inside my files by using linux 'file' and 'more' but this is not the case.

If I overwrite or turn off the height of the text input in inspect element tool the height is showing correct. As mention here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/246#issuecomment-7295682
Still the caret button size will show small..

However, I don't understand why the text input is showing correct on bootstraps own website:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms
Why don't they have the same issue?

Comment: Oh just found out that the difference between bootstraps site and mine is that I do see the doctype as first line in the inspect element tool and it is not showing up in mine.. weird as it is inside my header file as first line tho!

Comment: HTML is a big ugly hack. Millions of people use Postscript daily, but it is extremely rare to even look at it let alone debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm by viewing the actual source code there was code being outputted before the HTML and therefore the HTML doctype wasn't set. Moved it to the first line of the first file that is being called and it works now. Doh!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solves the problem. It will greatly help future visitors.