# Css doesn't appear properly in codeigniter view

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site made with CI & bootstrap. In this environment some css atributes don't appears properly. In CI I have a view like this:

```
<html>
    <head>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css2/bootstrap.css');?>"></link>      
    </head> 
  <body>
     <div class="container">            
        <input type="text" class="input-small" id="in_cod_horus" pattern="\D+\d{4,6}" maxlength="7">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the firebug's css computed inspector, the height property that is shown of the input text is:

> height: **6px**

meanwhile in the css file is:

> input[type="text"] → 16px     bootstrap.css:438

The controller is quite simple:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Merc_inicio extends CI_Controller {
  function index()
   {
    $this->load->view('plantilla');
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: The form elements (input, textarea, etc) have the `border-box` sizing. So the height is calculated including the padding. Check the padding values too.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element in Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug to see where it may have got overriden? CSS issues are best debugged there and not by inspection of stylesheets.

Comment: In IE 8 the height of the input works fine. :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot for sintax corrections :-)

Comment: This is not Codeigniter Issue. Mean CSS issue

Comment: Correct, ts8060. The solution is in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293294/bootstrap-text-input-wrong-height). Solved! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was a twitter-bootstrap / navigator rendering issue.
The solution here: [Bootstrap text input wrong height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293294/bootstrap-text-input-wrong-height)